# How to determine direction of the current in the following circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

What would be the direction of the current on R3? Can there be current moving in both directions?(left and right?)

Comment: It all depends on the values. For example, if R2=0 current will flow to the left; if R1=0 it will flow to the right.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @JohnRennie It's a concept I am trying to understand not homework.

Comment: From the information given you cannot ascertain the current direction, indeed there could be no current flowing through $R_3$.

Comment: @Farcher So how do I write Kirchhoff's Voltage Law if I don't know the positions of the negative and positive terminals on R3?

Comment: Simple. You assign a direction and do the sums. If the value of the current comes out to be positive then the current does flow in the direction that you originally assigned to it. If the value of the current comes out to be negative then the current is actually flowing in the opposite direction to that you originally assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I write Kirchhoff's Voltage Law if I don't know the positions of the negative and positive terminals on R3?

If you had a voltmeter, how do you *know in advance* which is the more positive terminal of $R_3$ to place the red (positive) probe of the voltmeter?  (of course,  the other probe is placed on the other terminal)

Answer:  *it doesn't matter*

Say that you place the red probe on the left-most terminal and you measure a positive voltage, then you now *know* the left-most terminal is the more positive terminal.

Now, reverse the probes; place the red probe on the right-most terminal and find that you measure a *negative* voltage, equal in magnitude to the previous measurement.  This tells you, again, that the left-most terminal is the more positive.

In other words, it doesn't matter which terminal you choose to place the red (positive) probe on, you will measure the correct voltage across *regardless*.

Now, for your KVL equations, say that you choose to label the left-most terminal as positive.  If you calculate a positive voltage across $R_3$, then you now *know* that the left-most terminal is the more positive terminal.

What do you think you would calculate if you had chosen to label the right-most terminal positive?  Just as with swapping leads of the voltmeter, you'll now calculate a *negative* voltage across which tells you, again, that the left-most terminal is the more positive terminal.

In other words, it doesn't matter which terminal you choose to label positive, your calculation will identify the more positive terminal *regardless*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there might be two currents in R3 one to the left and one to the right. To find out, assuming you have a value for the voltage, you can do three loop equations. For example, you can arbitrarily assign clockwise currents  I1 to the outer loop (V, R2, R5), I2 to the top loop (R1, R2, R3), and I3 to the lower loop (R3, R4, R5). Show polarities for the resistors based on current flowing from positive to negative. R3 will have two sets of polarities, one due to I2 and one due to I3. You have three equations and 3 unknowns. Solve for the three currents. If any turn out negative, it simply means the actual direction is opposite that assumed. Then the current in R3 will be the net contributions of I2 and I3.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The current through $R_3$ depends on the voltage across it. The voltage in each end is determined by the resistors that connect to the electrical source.

If $R_3$ was not there, the voltage at the left endpoint would be $V_+-(V_+-V_-)*R_1/(R_1+R_4)$, likewise the voltage at the right endpoint would be $V_+-(V_+-V_-)*R_2/(R_2+R_5)$. So, if $R_1/(R_1+R_4)>R_2/(R_2+R_5)$, voltage at the left side would be lower than voltage at the right side, and current would flow from left to right. And in the opposite case, it would flow the other way. And if the two numbers were the same, voltage would be the same at both ends, and no current would flow.

Of course, the voltages will vary with the size of $R_3$, and the relative size of the other resistors - but the direction of the flow remains the same.